# Mysql dat issue while using str to date

Tags: mysql

I have the data stored as this in my mysql table

http://prntscr.com/tbwiiq

I am trying to get the data based upon the order by clause

```
SELECT * FROM cw_books order by STR_TO_DATE(BookingTime, '%a, %d %b %Y %T') desc
```

but it is always giving me wrong order, what the best i can do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) that you use is wrong.
Use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cw_books 
order by STR_TO_DATE(BookingTime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayWgssgzaDZz1CsQGnVU3j/1).